# Why does this happen, and how to prevent it?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, subdivision-surface

8 and i started modeling a creature using mirror and subdivision modifier. Certain parts of the mesh act weird (see the picture) and i don'tknow what to do. When i apply the modifieres and start sculpting it does the opposite of what it was supposed to do (for example: i used Draw tool and instead of adding to a mesh it made a crease, if i want to add something to it i need to press ctrl). Please help.[image: How to fix this]

Comment: Try Recalculate normals in edit mode (Shift N, with all vertices selected)

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much!!